# H2O autoML does not stop after default time budget

Tags: h2o, automl, h2o.ai

Have your H2O ever exceeded the default training time budget (1 hour) and you had to stop it? what is your interpretation of this problem?

I am very familiar with this solution and this is happening for the very first time with a multiclass dataset of 20k instances, 40 features and 103 classes. However, surprisingly, when I lower the time budget to 15 mn (for example), h2O returns a model and makes predictions.

Thank you,

Yassine

Comment: Are you preferring to H2O AutoML?  Or a particular, individual H2O algorithm?

Comment: Sorry I was not precise. I was referring to h2o. autoML.